# Factory pattern with external dependency

Tags: c#, factory

I have a factory that makes objects that depend on an external object, do I pass it in the constructor of the factory?

Comment: Is there a better way?  Won't this factory be dependent on this external object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Factory Method calls object connstructor you should pass all necessary paramenters to factory method. Consider folowing:

```
class Foo {
} 

class Boo {
  public Boo(Foo foo) {}
}

static class BooFactory {
  public static Boo CreateBoo(Foo foo) {
     return new Boo(foo);
  }
}
```

Another alternative, as aaronls suggests, you can use [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_Control) to reduce such dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but you might want to look at inversion of control and dependency injection.  It takes a bit to get your head wrapped around, but it's a pattern for dealing specifically with dependencies.